# Recursively search folders with pattern and get files within it

Tags: windows, command-line

I wish to recursively search for all the folders with a particular name and get all the files inside the matched folder.

Example: If there exists a directory structure

```
C:\pa\10282019\iron
C:\pa\10282019\steel
C:\pa\10282019\steel\f1.txt
C:\pa\10282019\steel\f2.txt
C:\pa\10292019\iron
C:\pa\10292019\steel
C:\pa\10292019\steel\f3.txt
C:\pa\10292019\steel\f4.txt
```

The output I wish is - all the files inside steel folders.

```
C:\pa\10282019\steel\f1.txt
C:\pa\10282019\steel\f2.txt
C:\pa\10292019\steel\f3.txt
C:\pa\10292019\steel\f4.txt
```

And move them to a different directory.

Running the command

```
C:\pa>dir /s/b steel
```

Only outputs folder but not the files inside them. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it from a Command Prompt:

```
for /f %X in ('dir /s/b/ad *steel*') do for /f %Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d %X') do echo %Y >> out.txt
```

This searches for all folders whose name contains `steel` (use without the asterisks for names exactly equal to `steel`),
and then lists for each one all non-folder files,
adding their names to `out.txt`.

Ensure that the file `out.txt` is deleted before starting.

For inclusion in a `.bat` file, each `%` should be written as `%%`.

Reference : [The FOR /F command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: thank you. I have replaced `echo %Y` with **move** command, since I wanted to move those files to a different dir.